# Ubuntu Studio Freezes input keyboard and mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, freeze, ubuntu-studio

Ubuntu Studio 21.04 randomly "freezes" after several minutes, sometimes even at login screen.

Keyboard keys and mouse clicks stop being heard. Mouse pointer keeps on moving and also I can use F-keys to switch among terminals**. Once in one terminal I can type  and then kill the Xsession so everything start working again in a new fresh session.

Now installed 21.10 and updated as today with the same result.

This turns the computer completely unusable.

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I can’t actually see a question here; if you think there’s a bug, please file a report. If you just want to have a rant about it, I don’t think this site is a great place for it - this is a question and answer site where people will try to help if you frame an answerable question. If you want help from the community, please edit your question so we can try to answer it.

Comment: I apologize for the manners. I edited to explicit the question